# iOS 2 different nav bar images

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have replaced the nave bar in my iOS7 app in Xcode 5 using the following code (also removed the status bar if that matters):

AppDelegate.M

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In one of my image view controllers I am using a UIImagePicker to pick a profile pic. The problem is when it goes to the photo gallery it uses the main "navBar" image which hides some controls and basically stacks 2 of the same nav bars on top. Can I have a different nav bar for the photogallery? Here is the View controllers:

FirstView.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IBFirstViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userEmail;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImage;


- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)edit:(id)sender;
```

@end

FirstView.M

```
- (IBAction)edit:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:Nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem when using `[UINavigationBar appearance]` to custom navigation bar on iOS7. If we do that, all iOS native controller which is subclass of `UINavigationController`, is effected too, ex: `UIImagePickerController, MFMessageComposeViewController`...

If you want to use custom navigation style within your controllers, you have to apply with your `UINavigationController` instance instead of using `[UINavigationBar appearance]` singleton.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
     ... 
     UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
     [navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
     ...
}
```

Or in my case, I create subclass of UINavigationController

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupAppearance];
...
}

- (void)setupAppearance
{
    [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"]
}
```

Then, when you create UIImagePickerController instance, just custom its navigation bar

```
- (IBAction)edit:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    // Custom another navigation style
    [imagePickerController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NEW-NAV-BAR-IMAGE"];

    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:Nil];
}
```